How to upload files to a bucket from Design Automation without zipping the folder?
I have a design automation bundle for Revit.
This code saves two different files (.json and .rvt) to the “result” folder.
My activity has the following parameters
Parameters Image
If I set the result parameter zip true, the result is fine, but I get an archived file(result.zip) in bucket.
I need to get these two files into bucket without archiving.
I want to have on bucket files that will not be archived(result.zip).
Any ideas on how to do this?

DA does not know how to do this for you, so you have to do this yourself: your appbundle will need to include code that does the uploading. You should also remove the "result" output parameter since DA should no longer do the uploading.

Thank you for your comment. How can I upload the result file to bucket using the source code (bundle)? Can you write a short code example or share where it is done?

@Oleh if you want to upload the files to your APS developer managed bucket, then you must call APS OSS API inside your Revit addin(appbundle). Here is an example of using our .NET SDK to upload the files to APS OSS bucket: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-simple-viewer-dotnet/blob/develop/Models/APS.Oss.cs#L42

@EasonKang Thanks for the advice. As a result it looks like my part of the API will move to bundle, which doesn't sound good. And I only need to work with 2 result files, I will create two result parameters in the activity that will be uploaded to bucket.
